# Add Special Case to Power BI Query (M)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm currently using Power BI's query editor to unpivot, transform, join, re-pivot and re-join some data. Illustrating:

REF_Capability:

```
ID#| Capability.1 | Capability.2 | Capability.3| 
97 | Crawl        | Walk         | Run         |
98 | Crawl        | null         | null        |
99 | Crawl        | Walk         | null        |
```

Table2:

```
Capability | Attribute| Value | 
Crawl      | Vehicle1 | 4     |
Walk       | Vehicle1 | 3     |
Run        | Vehicle1 | 2     |
Crawl      | Vehicle2 | 0     |
Walk       | Vehicle2 | 1     |
Run        | Vehilce2 | 1     |
Crawl      | Vehicle3 | 0     |
Walk       | Vehicle3 | 5     |
Run        | Vehicle3 | 5     |
```

Using a combination of unpivoting, filtering, merging queries, expanding columns and re-pivoting and re-merging I get this OutputTable:

```
ID#| Capability.1 | Capability.2 | Capability.3| Score.Vehicle1    | Score.Vehicle2    | Score.Vehicle3   | 
97 | Crawl        | Walk         | Run         | 9 [4+3+2]         | 2 [0+1+1]         | 10 [0+5+5]       |
98 | Crawl        | null         | null        | 4 [4+null+null]   | 0 [0+null+null]   | 0 [0+null+null]  |
99 | Crawl        | Walk         | null        | 7 [4+3+null]      | 1 [0+1+null]      | 5 [0+5+null]     |
```

In the case of ID#97 under Vehicle2CapaScore and Vechile3CapaScore instead of scores of 2 and 10 respectively I would like score of 0 for both. Explaining... if a Vehicle has an outright score of 0 for ANY particular capability it scores a 0 for all capabilities. Or more simply, it doesn't matter how good you are at walking or running if you can't crawl.

I would like some help working that logic into my query:

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("SOURCE_vti_bin/listdata.svc"),
    REF_Capability = Source{[ID#="REF_Capability",Signature="table"]}[Data],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Table1,"Capability",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("; ", QuoteStyle.Csv),{"Capability.1", "Capability.2", "Capability.3"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Capability.1", type text}, {"Capability.2", type text}, {"Capability.3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Change Type", {"ID#"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Attribute] = "Capability.1" or [Attribute] = "Capability.2" or [Attribute] = "Capability.3") and ([Value] <> "")),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows",{"Value"},Table2,{"Capability"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "NewColumn", {"Attribute", "Value"}, {"VehicleScore.Attribute", "VehicleScore.Value"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded NewColumn",{"Attribute", "Value"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[VehicleScore.Attribute]), "VehicleScore.Attribute", "VehicleScore.Value", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"

let
    Source = OData.Feed("SOURCE/_vti_bin/ListData.svc"),
    OutputTable = Source{[ID#="OutputTable",Signature="table"]}[Data],
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#OutputTable,{"ID#"},REF_Capability,{"ID#"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "NewColumn", {"Vehicle1", "Vehicle2", "Vehicle3"}, {"Score.Vehicle1","Score.Vehicle2", "Score.Vehicle3"})
in
    #"Expanded NewColumn"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a Group By with Min calc to the to find Vehicles with a 0. Then I'd Add a Column and write a simple if statement e.g.

`if [Min Value] = 0 then 0 else [Sum Value]`

Comment: I see what you did here... and yes it works. I'm curious though... have you seen that MS added "conditional columns" in the last update of PowerBI. Ergo, wouldn't it be more efficient to use that rather than having to rejoin/merge the query your suggesting back to the table that existed prior to the minvalue step? (I can't test as I'm waiting for our IT shop to run the executable on my laptop)

Comment: The new "conditional columns" feature is just an easier UI to generate an Added Column with the same "if" code above, so there is no efficiency gain at runtime.

Comment: You can achieve it all in one Query if you add an "All Rows" aggregated column during the Group By (where you calculate [Min Value]). You can immediately expand the "All Rows" column to get your detail back.